# Delay in javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I have many linked Javascript files which I need to debug from the point they start executing. I am using the inbuilt debugger in chrome for this purpose. But by the time I am able to open the debugger, the script has already completed the part I want to debug. So, is there a standard way built in chrome (or any other debugger, though I would like to stick to chrome) to stall the execution for debugging. I want to avoid putting a delay like function in my script.

Also, reloading the script is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in Developer Tools. When the interpretor gets to that line, it will break, allowing you to examine a few things.

[image: Example]

Not the best example, because Stack Overflow's JavaScript is minified, but you get the idea.

Comment: This wouldn't help in the scenario where the JavaScript is executed in a new tab created by a parent tab.

Comment: @Kartik What would the difference be?

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
function name() 
{    
         debugger;
        // you code 
  }
```

in you code

Comment: Works in firefox, not in chrome.